GMSPinImageOptions - Not able to find "GMSPinImageOptions" in scope iOS
I am using Google Maps SDK in my iOS app. When I try to use GMSPinImageOptions in my code. I am not able to use it even though I have imported GoogleMaps. It keeps saying,
Cannot find 'GMSPinImageOptions' in scope

Here is what I am doing,
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSMarker {
    
    func setTintColor(_ tint: UIColor) {
    
        let options = GMSPinImageOptions() // Cannot find 'GMSPinImageOptions' in scope
        options.backgroundColor = tint

        let pinImage = GMSPinImage(options: options) // Cannot find 'GMSPinImage' in scope
        icon = pinImage
        
    }
    
}

Am I missing some imports or anything else?
Also here are the official docs I am referring to, Marker Customization

Are the other classes like the GMSAdvancedMarker class working just fine along side this issue? Did you also make sure that you are using the latest version of Maps SDK for iOS? Since Advanced Markers capabilities would not be available on older versions. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/advanced-markers/overview#:~:text=Advanced%20marker%20capabilities%20were%20released%20in%20Google%20Maps%20SDK%208.0.0%20for%20iOS%2014%2B.%20Versions%20iOS%2013%20and%20below%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20Google%20Maps%20SDK%208.0.0.

To be more specific, Advanced Marker capabilities were released in version 8.0.0 of Maps SDK for iOS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/release-notes#September_19_2023
